# Clickable notifications that allow to interact with programs which have spawned them?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification, system-tray

There are Notifications in KDE's System Tray.

The problem is that Notifications don't provide access to the apps that spawn those notifications. The only available action is to dismiss the notification.

For example, a notification pops up and tells me that an archive extraction has been finished. I would like to click that notification for the extracted files to be opened in a file manager. Instead, i have to manually browse for those files.

Or a notification pops up and tells me that there are system updates available. I would like to click the notification to access the updates manager (or even immediately initiate the update). Instead, i have to look for the update manager's icon and open it manually.

Is there a way to enhance the Notification system to enable that? Or there's some Plasma widget capable of interacting with notifications?

Comment: Have you find something to interact with by example the shell ?

Answer (score 1):

**KDE notifications**

KDE doc page: http://docs.kde.org/development/en/kde-runtime/kcontrol/kcmnotify/index.html

KDE UserBase page: http://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Application_and_System_Notifications

**Alternative notifications**

Colibri: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Colibri?content=117147+kde-apps.org+page

> Colibri notifications look lighter and are completely passive: they do
>   not provide any buttons. You may or may not like this...

Ubuntu package available: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=colibri&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

USU Notifications: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/?content=158063

> Alternative KDE notifications, based on QML and org.kde.notofications,
>   but with more features...

The USU notifications seem to have the option 'to click that notification for the extracted files to be opened in a file manager'

[image]

It is a scrip -> Add Widgets > Get New widgets... [image]

- Right click the System Tray
- System Tray Settings
- Disable the standard notifications and enable the USU

[image]

Comment: Thanks, can you show an example of interaction with the shell and USU please ? I would like to open a link. The link appears but is not clickable with by example `notify-send -t 500000 "test" '<a href="http:/google.com">google</a>'`